# Google Drive: Xamarin - Android GetInputStream - can only be called once per Content Instance

Tags: xamarin, google-drive-api, inputstream, drive

I have the Google drive opened and the files are selectable. After clicking the confirmation button, I will have a response and call the `InputStream` and start reading the file. This was my code which read the `InputStream`.

```
var pendingResult = driveFile.OpenAsync(GoogleApiClient, DriveFile.ModeReadOnly, this)
            .ContinueWith((resultTask) =>
            {
                var driveContentResults = resultTask.Result;
                var driveContent = driveContentResults.DriveContents;

                if (_dialog != null && _dialog.IsShowing)
                    _dialog.Dismiss();

                if (driveContentResults.Status.IsSuccess)
                {
                    if (FileReadyCallback != null)
                    { 
                        var length = driveContent.InputStream.Length;
                        //var data = new byte[length];
                        //driveContent.InputStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        //FileReadyCallback(this, data);
                    }
                    //var absolutePath = FileUtilities.SaveStreamToDownloadDirectory(driveContent.InputStream, Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf");
                    //SendResultToCallingActivity(absolutePath);
                }

            });
```

When the application reached to `driveContent.InputStream.Length`, the breakpoint showed me that the `InputStream` can only be called once per Content Instance. In the code, that line is my first call of the input stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, instead of calling `driveContent.InputStream` every time, make a variable named `input` and assign `driveContent.InputStream`, then use `input` to read bytes, get length or other methods.

```
var input = driveContent.InputStream
```

and then replace with

```
var length = input.Length;
```

and

```
input.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
```